# Replace whole Series values by an array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that look like this:

```
13624    A
25257    D
15359    D
26226    D
10797    D
        ..
9733     D
25121    D
10143    C
1448     B
13627    B
Name: points, Length: 10189, dtype: object
```

And I want to apply the `LabelEncoder()` function from `sklearn.preprocessing` and replace all the values.

The `le.fit_transform(y_train)` function returns this:

```
array([0, 3, 3, ..., 2, 1, 1])
```

This array is ordered by the original index, so the idea is to replace exactly the value column with this array.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating a new series with the same index and reassign back:

```
y_train = pd.Series(le.fit_transform(y_train), index=y_train.index)
```

Comment: Oh, good idea. Simple and it is working. Thank you :)